# A problem on G-Space (Trivial Bundle)

Tags: fiber-bundles

Suppose $A$ is a $G$-space and we let $\pi:A \rightarrow A/G$ be a principle $G$ bundle with cross section that is continuous $s:A/G \rightarrow A$. That means we have $\pi \circ s = id_{A/G}$. I need to show that $\pi:A \rightarrow A/G$ is a trivial bundle.

Do I have to find a homeomorphism $h$ such that $h:A \rightarrow A/G \times F$ where $F$ is the fibre? How can I construct the map $h$? Or I have to show that $A=A/G \times F$?

Comment: Yes, but you (a) know the fiber and (b) must have a homeo consistent with the original bundle.

Comment: So what can be the fibre here?